# Fuzzy Matching Names and Joining Multiple Data Sources

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, join, oracle11g

I have three different tables that I need to join onto each other. The only unique identifier is the names of employees, but the names are not normalized. I've installed a fuzzy function to use, but I'm not sure how I can use the fuzzy match to join on the multiple tables.

- table 1 name - Matt Le-Hall
- table 2 name  - Matt Hal
- table 3 name -  Matt Hall

If I do a:

```
select * from table 1, table 2, table 3
where table name 1 = table name 2
and table name 2 = table name 3
```

The results won't populate due to names being in different normalization, BUT I can use a fuzzy function to get me a certain percentage of similarity between each name column in each table.

My question is: how can I use a fuzzy function in order to join these tables together by non-normalized names?

Comment: read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question. it is really hard to help with insufficient info.

Comment: this is really not a small topic.  You can research things like string comparison, deduplication, and more.  Bottom line is it depends on your database, your character set (us only?) and more.  Most answers will be a combination of Jaro-Winkler with NGrams and/Levenstein string comparisons or a bunch of other methods.  Fuzzy is relative and depends on the exactness needed of the results.  Microsoft for sql-server actually has a product called Data Quality Services which has some functions and capabilities targeted at this.  MS SSIS fuzzy matching isn't good enough for most situations and......